# Getting Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp error while using fillna in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I am getting `out of bounds nanosecond timestamp` error while trying to pass default value to null value column

```
df3['check_date']=df3['eventDate0142'].fillna(df3['statusDateTi'].fillna(pd.to_datetime('9999-12-31')))
```

How can this be fixed.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in pandas [maximal Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations) is:

```
print (pd.Timestamp.max)
2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807
```

So in pandas is raised error:

```
print (pd.to_datetime('9999-12-31'))
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00
```

**Sample**:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'eventDate0142': [np.nan,  np.nan, '2016-04-01'], 
                   'statusDateTi': [np.nan, '2019-01-01', '2017-04-01']})

df3 = df1.apply(pd.to_datetime)

print (df3)
  eventDate0142 statusDateTi  
0           NaT          NaT 
1           NaT   2019-01-01  
2    2016-04-01   2017-04-01
```

Possible solution is use pure python, but then all pandas datetimelike methods failed - all data convert to `date`s:

```
from datetime import  date

print (date.fromisoformat('9999-12-31'))
9999-12-31


df3['check_date'] = (df3['eventDate0142'].dt.date
                        .fillna(df3['statusDateTi'].dt.date
                        .fillna(date.fromisoformat('9999-12-31'))))
print (df3)
  eventDate0142 statusDateTi  check_date
0           NaT          NaT  9999-12-31
1           NaT   2019-01-01  2019-01-01
2    2016-04-01   2017-04-01  2016-04-01

print (df3.dtypes)
eventDate0142    datetime64[ns]
statusDateTi     datetime64[ns]
check_date               object
dtype: object
```

Or convert timestamps to daily periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html), and then use `Periods` for [representing out of bounds spans](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans):

```
print (pd.Period('9999-12-31'))
9999-12-31

df3['check_date'] = (df3['eventDate0142'].dt.to_period('d')
                        .fillna(df3['statusDateTi'].dt.to_period('d')
                        .fillna(pd.Period('9999-12-31'))))
print (df3)
  eventDate0142 statusDateTi  check_date
0           NaT          NaT  9999-12-31
1           NaT   2019-01-01  2019-01-01
2    2016-04-01   2017-04-01  2016-04-01

print (df3.dtypes)
eventDate0142    datetime64[ns]
statusDateTi     datetime64[ns]
check_date            period[D]
dtype: object
```

If assign back all columns:

```
df3['eventDate0142'] = df3['eventDate0142'].dt.to_period('d')
df3['statusDateTi'] = df3['statusDateTi'].dt.to_period('d')
df3['check_date'] = (df3['eventDate0142']
                        .fillna(df3['statusDateTi']
                        .fillna(pd.Period('9999-12-31'))))
print (df3)
  eventDate0142 statusDateTi  check_date
0           NaT          NaT  9999-12-31
1           NaT   2019-01-01  2019-01-01
2    2016-04-01   2017-04-01  2016-04-01

print (df3.dtypes)
eventDate0142    period[D]
statusDateTi     period[D]
check_date       period[D]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Getting an error `Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: @LDF_VARUM_ELLAM_SHERIAAVUM - Exactly it is problem if use `9999-12-31`. Solution is only use `Periods` in pandas. Or if possible not replace by `9999-12-31`

Comment: I didnt get you

Comment: @LDF_VARUM_ELLAM_SHERIAAVUM - Ok, in pandas datetime `9999-12-31` cannot use, if want use `.dt` function, because maximal datetime is `2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807`

Comment: @LDF_VARUM_ELLAM_SHERIAAVUM - So if use `date.fromisoformat('9999-12-31')` then is column converted to object then cannot use `.dt` functions.

Comment: @LDF_VARUM_ELLAM_SHERIAAVUM - Only pandas way with `9999-12-31` is converting timespamp to daily periods by `.dt.to_period('d')`, so possible use `pd.Period('9999-12-31')`

Comment: still its not working.`df13['default_date']= pd.Period('9999-12-31')`
`df13.default_date = pd.to_datetime(df13.default_date).dt.date`. I am getting another error `Passing PeriodDtype data is invalid. Use `data.to_timestamp()` instead`

Comment: @LDF_VARUM_ELLAM_SHERIAAVUM - yes, you mix dates with daily periods. Check my last solution.

Comment: or can we create new column with default value `9999-12-31` and then replace this value

Comment: @LDF_VARUM_ELLAM_SHERIAAVUM - yes, if need new column then possible use, if dont need new column not necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225449/discussion-between-ldf-varum-ellam-sheriaavum-and-jezrael).